# How to transcribe raw audio data with picovoice leopard and pyaudio

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio

I'm trying to find a way to transcribe raw audio data with picovoice leopard model.
in the official picovoice docs there is a few lines of code explaining how to do so, but I could not get it done.

From the official docs:

```py
transcript, words = leopard.process(get_audio_data())
print(transcript)
for word in words:
    print(
      "{word=\"%s\" start_sec=%.2f end_sec=%.2f confidence=%.2f}"
      % (word.word, word.start_sec, word.end_sec, word.confidence))
```

Now let's say I'm reading microphone input with pyaudio like this:

```py
AUDIO_FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 
AUDIO_CHANNELS = 1  
SAMPLE_RATE = 16000 
CHUNK_SIZE = 512

def get_audio_data():
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format=AUDIO_FORMAT, channels=AUDIO_CHANNELS,
                            rate=SAMPLE_RATE, input=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK_SIZE)
    frames = []
    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
        frames.append(data)
        if #condition: 
            break
    return frames
```

So when trying to process the data I get the following exception:

`TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

in the line
`transcript, words = leopard.process(frames)`

I could not find anything about picovoice on the web except the [official docs](https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/leopard-python/)

Comment: Please print the value of the `frames` variable.

Comment: @KathyReid
```frames``` is just a list of bytes:

```[b'\x02\x00\x01\x00\xfd\xff\xfd\xff\xfb\xff\xff\xff\x03\x00\x08\x00\n\x00\n\x00\........']```

Comment: Looking at the [source code for the `pvleopard` module](https://github.com/Picovoice/leopard/blob/7479dcad0d6bbb7617369002b68991e24b97c446/binding/python/_leopard.py#L206), the `process()` function is expecting a sequence of integers, not a bytestream. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629496/get-an-audio-sample-as-float-number-from-pyaudio-stream) shows you how to convert the bytes to a sequence of integers.

Comment: now its working with no errors, but the transcript is empty.



```decoded = numpy.frombuffer(stream.read(SIZE), 'int16')


transcript, words = leopard.process(decoded)
```

Comment: What other troubleshooting have you done? Do you have your PicoVoice AccessKey set up correctly - see https://picovoice.ai/docs/quick-start/leopard-python/#picovoice-account--accesskey

Comment: I managed to fix it, the problem was with my condition.