# Python speech to text from mikrofon stream

Tags: python, speech-recognition, whisper

I want to programm my own speech assistent with python and run it on a rapsberry pi later on. My first step to do this is to transcribe the speech of a microfon stream.
So I want the speech that my microphone receives to be immediately converted to text so that I can then check this text for signal words such as "Hey Siri".

I have already tried most of the STT APIs, such as speech recognition, whisper and Google Cloud Speech_To_Text. I had the problem with all of them that they weren't transcribing during the stream. For example speech recognition waited until I stopped speaking. This recorded audio file was then sent to the servers and transcribed. This took a very long time.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know any service which can do it. Even Google Assistant on Android is waiting for end of speech. If you send only part of speech then it may not know what you really want to say because it can depends on full content.

Comment: as I remember there are programs to convert Raspberry Pi into Assistant and they may use different method - first they record sound and compare with some local file to detect `"Hey Siri"` and later they record rest of speech and send to Google Speech to convert it.

Comment: I never test it but there is `mycroft` which you can [download](https://mycroft.ai/get-started/) as `Picroft` and install on `Raspberry`. And probably all code is in `Python` - see [source code](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem you are trying to solve here is the real-time transcription of *streaming* audio. The `SpeechRecognition` library for Python is capable of doing this, but requires some additional manipulation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77532364/how-to-transcribe-raw-audio-data-with-picovoice-leopard-and-pyaudio#comment136755047_77532364) for more information.